# Better Way To Start Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a coding style question. Given the following code below, which uses http service to retrieve data and then uses the controller to execute that service/factory. It just seems like calling the function makePromise() at the end of the controller is not the "correct" way to do things. It works, but is there a better way to execute this code? Maybe a best practice? I just can't imagine having for example 10 or so executing statements at the end of a controller...just doesn't seem right. I'm just looking for a more elegant solution.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('DataService', function($http, $q) {
return {
getData: function() {
  return $http.get('http://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json')
    .then(function(response) {
      if (typeof response.data == 'object') {
        return response.data;
      } else {
        return $q.reject(response.data);
      }
    }, function(response) {
      return $q.reject(response.data);
    })
  }
 }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, DataService) {
$scope.driversList = [];
var makePromise = function() {
DataService.getData()
  .then(function(data) {
    //console.log(data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings)
    $scope.driversList = data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('error')
  })
}
//THIS IS MY CONCERN HERE...
makePromise();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to wrap it in a function. A lot of time my code looks similar to this.

```
DataService.getData()
 .then(function(data) {
//console.log(data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings)
  $scope.driversList = data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
}, function(error) {
 console.log('error')
})
```

There are 2 alternatives, the first is using ng-init="loadStuff()" in your html. A cleaner solution is probably using Resolve within UI-Router. So your loading data on the route change and possibly showing a loader while GETs are being made.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question!
The best way what I found is the following function:

```
(function () { // init
    // initialize values on your scope
})();
```

The directive ng-init doesn't recommended to use it to load controllers.

"You should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope."
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit